# jquery on hover does not work on bootstrap tree view

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is not expected as on li the jquery `onhover` trigger anonymous function . my html structure is

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "fetch.php",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#treeview').treeview({data: data});
            }
        });

    });
    $("#treeview").on('click','.list-group', function () {
//   var t = $(this).find('li');
        alert('here');
        console.log($(this));
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width:900px;">

  <div id="treeview">

  </div>
</div>
```

but `onhover` of li the jquery function is not triggering 
after ajax respond my html structure become like this

```html
<div id="treeview" class="treeview">
 <ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item node-treeview node-selected" data-nodeid="0" style="color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#428bca;"><span class="icon expand-icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span class="icon node-icon"></span>USA</li>
  <li class="list-group-item node-treeview" data-nodeid="13" style="color:undefined;background-color:undefined;"><span class="icon expand-icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span class="icon node-icon"></span>Canada</li>
  <li class="list-group-item node-treeview" data-nodeid="20" style="color:undefined;background-color:undefined;"><span class="icon expand-icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span class="icon node-icon"></span>Australia</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

but jquery is not triggering `onhover` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```js
              
 $("#treeview").on('mouseover','.list-group-item', function () {
                        console.log($(this).html());
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="width:900px;">

         <div id="treeview" class="treeview">
     <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item node-treeview node-selected" data-nodeid="0" style="color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#428bca;"><span class="icon expand-icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span class="icon node-icon"></span>USA</li>
      <li class="list-group-item node-treeview" data-nodeid="13" style="color:undefined;background-color:undefined;"><span class="icon expand-icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span class="icon node-icon"></span>Canada</li>
      <li class="list-group-item node-treeview" data-nodeid="20" style="color:undefined;background-color:undefined;"><span class="icon expand-icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span class="icon node-icon"></span>Australia</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: thanks you figuered it out . can i ask why on hover is not working while mouceover does ?? any logic specified here ?

Answer (score 1):

for hovering onclick is not right mouseover event is right

```
$("#treeview").on('mouseover','.list-group', function () {

        alert('here');
        console.log($(this));

 })
```